# Postgis ST_UNION TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point

Tags: postgis

I have a dataset containing zip and its geom. I am trying to aggregate the geom to a higher zip level.

For example, the area of zip 123 should be area(1234) + area(1235) - their overlap.

I am calling ST_UNION(the geom), but get error saying

```
ERROR: GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point xxx
```

Anyone had similar error?

Comment: You have invalid geometries in your data set. Try `SELECT * from table WHERE NOT ST_isvalid(th_geom)`;